# Can't compile and link with dynamic library

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world by defining the function in a shared lib, but when compiling the main program I get:

```
/tmp/hello-ca67ea.o: In the function 'main':
hello.c:(.text+0x1a): reference to 'greeting(char const*)' not defined
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried both with *Clang* and *GCC* and the same error happens.

I already searched SO but didn't find anything similar.

The *directory* is as follows:

```
shared-test
 |
 |--greeting.c
 |--greeting.h
 |--hello.c
```

**hello.c**

```
#include "greeting.h"

int main ()
{
    greeting("Daniel");
    return 0;
}
```

**greeting.h**

```
#ifndef GREETING_H
#define GREETING_H

void greeting(const char* text);

#endif
```

**greeting.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "greeting.h"

void greeting(const char* text)
{
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

**greeting.so** is being compiled with `clang greeting.c -o greeting.so -shared -fPIC`

And I'm trying to compile hello with `clang hello.c -o hello -Igreeting`

Can anyone help me find what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clang hello.c -o hello -Igreeting`

attempts to compile **and link**, but you didn't supply the name of the library to link with:

```
clang hello.c -o hello -Igreeting greeting.so #<= greeting.so added
```

Then you should be able to run the output with:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./hello
```

The idea is that the lib will be put in one of your systems library paths and because you haven't done that, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is a kind of a hack to make it work without it.

With gcc/clang on Linux, you can also hardcode the full path:

```
clang hello.c -o hello -Igreeting $PWD/greeting.so
```

or you can make the dynamic linker search for the dependency relative to the location of the executable

```
clang hello.c -o hello -Igreeting '-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN' greeting.so
```

With either of the two methods above, you don't need the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` part anymore.

There's a lot more to dynamic libraries, and I recommend you study up more on them e.g., from Ulrich Drepper's [DSO Howto](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) writeup.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. Is there a way to run it without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH? or to tell the executable to search for the object in the same directory?

Comment: @DanielP. Yes and yes. I've expanded the answer.